# При передачи данных с firebase выходит ошибка

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

При логированнии в приложении с firebase выходит ошибка в функции которая парсит данные , эти данные `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

APIManager - тут функции парсинга данных с firebase, в `let doc = Document(email: document?.get("email") as! String, nickname: document?.get("nickname") as! String, userName: document?.get("userName") as! String, userLastName: document?.get("userLastName") as! String, userDateBirth: document?.get("userDateBirth") as! String)`
Выходят ошибка

```
class APIManager {
    static let shared = APIManager()
    
    // MARK: - Config
    private func configFB()->Firestore{
        var db:Firestore!
        let setting = FirestoreSettings()
        Firestore.firestore().settings = setting
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        return db
    }
    
    // MARK: - Get info from db
    
    func getPost(collection:String, docName:String, completion:@escaping(Document?)-> Void){
        let db = configFB()
        db.collection(collection).document(docName).getDocument { (document, error) in
            guard error == nil else {completion(nil); return }
            let doc = Document(email: document?.get("email") as! String, nickname: document?.get("nickname") as! String, userName: document?.get("userName") as! String, userLastName: document?.get("userLastName") as! String, userDateBirth: document?.get("userDateBirth") as! String)
            completion(doc)
        }
    }
```

это из класса с логированием

```
    @IBAction func didTapLoginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) {(result,error) in
            if error != nil{
                print("ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ НЕ НАЙДЕТ !")
            }else{
                print("Авторизация прошла успешно")
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
                UserSettings.userID = userID
                print("------------------USER-ID-----------------")
                print("USER ID          \(userID)")
                print("------------------USER-ID-----------------")
                APIManager.shared.getPost(collection: "users", docName: "\(UserSettings.userID)", completion: {doc in
                    guard doc != nil else{return}
                    var name = doc?.nickname
                    var email = doc?.email
                    print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------")
                    print("User NAME: \(name)")
                    var VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuTableViewController")
                    guard let menuViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier:"MenuTableViewController" ) as? MenuTableViewController else {return}
                    menuViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                    guard let tabBarViewContorller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier:"TabBAR" ) as? TabBarViewController else {return}
                    self.tabBarController?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                    self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil) // на SB
                        }
                    )}
                }
            
            }
```

Все поля все правильно заполнены из firebase  в APIManager
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Нашел проблему , у меня в памяти телефона остается старый userID из за `UserSettings.userID` заменив на userID который взят из firebase на пряму , заработало ,но Вот теперь думаю как очистить из памяти  телефона старые данные ?  Использую `UserDefaults` но надо удалять по всем ключам сразу данные